# Config Error : I'm unable to connect my DB using Moodle

Tags: mysql, mariadb, moodle

Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

Below My Config.php

```
unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = '192.0.0.0';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'admindb@123';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => 3306,
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
);
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://192.0.0.0/moodle-apexon';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C://xampp//moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';
```

Comment: New to moodle. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Using $CFG->dbhost as " localhost " may fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the database via the command line. If that doesn't work then check the username, password, dbname etc.

```
mysql --user=root --password=admindb@123 --host=192.0.0.0 moodle
```